# Windows 10 Search Cannot Find Some Programs in Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, search

I've been having this issue for a certain time now. It goes something like this: when I install a program, there's a 50/50 chance of it being searchable, even though it is already in the start menu (searchable as in it comes up when I `windows key + search word`). If it so happens that the program is searchable, it stays searchable even if I uninstall it (the top result is an unclickable shortcut).

Here are some of the searchable programs I've installed today:
Google Chrome, Steam

Some of the unsearchable programs:
Firefox Quantum, Google Earth Pro

I'm using the windows creator update, and I've tried all of the potential solutions described here as well as the no-brainers such as reindexing and troubleshooting tool:
[Windows 10 Search can't find ANY applications. Even calculator](https://superuser.com/questions/947392/windows-10-search-cant-find-any-applications-even-calculator?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Are you using too many words? E.G. search on "firefox", not "firefox quantum".

Comment: Nope, I'm searching for "firefox" or simply "fire". It would seem as if windows is not trying to look for my search phrase in the index at all (or has somehow indexed wrongly).

Comment: I have the same problem, mine resolved with [this solution](http://superuser.com/a/1393119/325072)